# How does netcat communicate with various server ports

Tags: netcat

I am trying to understand how `netcat` is able to communicate with so many different ports. I can think of there being one of two ways:

1. `netcat` simply does a `TCP SYN` and initiates the 3-way handshake. If `netcat` receives `SYN + ACK` from the server then it concludes that the port is good.
2. Or perhaps `netcat` implements client for various application layer protocols such as http, ssh, sftp, dns etc.

Any ideas as to which of the two approaches does `netcat` take in its implementation?

Comment: Your question is missing quite a lot of context. What are you trying to do exactly? What command(s) are you running? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the question is around how `netcat` is implemented. I am not having trouble running commands. Just curious about how it is able to handle so many protocols.